# How to get an user's GPS location automatically without his/her permission in Android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm beginner in Android development and I just wonder that, is there anyway to get an Android user's GPS location automatically without his/her permission? A bit more detail, when he or she hits a button, his/her current exact location will be instantly sent into my device?

I'm not a hacker or a bad guy. I just want to know.

Comment: No, you cannot know my exact location unless I allow it. If you could then why would anybody ever ask for the permission?

Comment: Well.....I meant, just example, I have an application which has a button, and when someone tap on it, his/her location will be sent to me?
He/She will know that the button can send his/her location to me and will decide whether to tap on it or not, so that's a permission, isn't it?
Is there any ways? Just a last confirm, pls :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there anyway to get an Android user's GPS location automatically without his/her permissions?

Fortunately no, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: Well.....I meant, just example, I have an application which has a button, and when someone tap on it, his/her location will be sent to me?
He/She will know that the button can send his/her location to me and will decide whether to tap on it or not, so that's a permission, isn't it?
Is there any ways? Just a last confirm, pls :'(

Comment: @TrầnHữuNhậtHuy: "so that's a permission, isn't it?" -- only if you go through the Android permission system. "He/She will know that the button can send his/her location to me" -- then you should have no problems in using the Android permission system, so the *user* can tell the *device* that your app is authorized to have access to the device's location.